# Extract multiple different lines matching in a text file VBScript

Tags: regex

I need to extract orders from a PDF file, I have converted the PDF into text but I am having trouble understanding Expressions could someone give me a small example of how to build an expression that would look for a block of text held on different lines.

Sequence:

```
ORDER NUMBER :   SO773175            Ship Date: 23-Nov-15

      Style Desc : CURTAINS CR 46X54
      Linecode : J855566
      Qty              36
```

It doesn't matter if I just save the values after the : or the whole block, the block of text is repeated for each individual order so could be 5 or could be 50 orders in one file, but these blocks are only repeated once in the entire file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you're having problems with the multiple lines, \n is the regex newline character, so, if you are using a regex engine that does perl like regular expressions (most of them), then this should work.

```
ORDER NUMBER :\s+[^\s]+\s+Ship Date:\s+[^\s]+\n\n\s+Style Desc : .+\n\s+Linecode : .+\n\s+Qty\s+.+
```

I would recommend https://regex101.com/, or any of the other regex testing sites out there as a good place to test out creating regex expressions.

Comment: thank you for your sample, gave me a really good foundation of how to represent patterns, Unfortunately this does not work with the new Regex function in .NET 4.5 some reason it does not return the matches like it does in Regex 101. If I split the sample you provided up it returns the order number part of the match but not when I add second part, tried grouping them but think they have dropped the modifiers like g  so had to go with a FSO and splitting the text file into single arrays.

Comment: hi please could you show me an example of how I would use this, as I have tried implementing in VBA but not getting a result have you any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
ORDER\sNUMBER\s:\s+(\w+)\s+Ship\sDate:\s+(\w{2}-\w{3}-\w{2})\s+Style\sDesc\s:\s([^\n]+)\s+Linecode\s:\s(\w+)\s+Qty\s+(\d+)
```

Values are in different groups.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sD7rF9/1)

Comment: thanks for your example, gave me a headache at first trying to understand it but the demo really helped as well, very logical with the groups and groupings, unfortunately as above couldn't get it working in a VB script task .NET 4.5 as the function Regexp has now changed to Regex different methods not all included in new function

Comment: hi please could you show me an example of how I would use this as I have tried implementing in VBA but not getting a result have you any ideas please ?